# ActiveRecord return a record along top 5 records in the JOIN clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have one to many relationship with between an image and comments.
I want to return images but along with images latest 5 (sorted by their primary id) comments of that particular image.

Is this possible in ActiveRecord? How can I construct the 5 comments in such a way that ruby will detect/convert it into an array?

P.S. I want to do this in 1 query. I know I can query images, and then for each image get the 5 comments, but that's inefficient. I want to do this in one go.

I am not providing the database schema because it's just a simple 1 to many relationship. comments table has a column called image_id.

Thanks

Comment: Others seem to understand this question as is, but can you explain what you mean by "top comments"? Can the same exact comment (i.e. same comment string) appear multiple times for the same image? Does "top" refer to the number of occurrences of that particular comment?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin by top comments, i mean the latest comment (sorted by their primary id). Same comment cannot appear multiple times. Actually, forgot I even said top. It should have same effect as doing  LIMIT 5 .

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do what you are describing with ActiveRecord. Actually, there's no good way to do this in SQL either, short of constructing a monstrous query with a lot of self joins. Since ActiveRecord retrieves data by generating SQL queries, it has the same limitations as SQL.

The easiest thing to do would be to retrieve *all* the comments for each image, and then pick off 5 of each. If the number of comments per image may be large, and retrieving all of them would make you miss your performance goals, there are a variety of possible solutions. If you post more details, perhaps someone can suggest what an appropriate solution would be. (For example: what DB are you using? How many images are there? How  many comments per image, on average? How fast does this have to be?)

Comment: Using MySQL. There are around 6,000 images, average 2 comments per image. My query right now runs in 140ms, should be around this time. Do you suggest I use in memory db for this like redis?

Comment: OK. That is a very easy performance target to hit; likely there will be no need to do anything really special. I just tried SELECTing 12,000 rows from one of my MySQL DBs, and it took 160ms. So just retrieving the data from MySQL in the simplest possible manner may be fast enough for you. If you want something faster, there are a few options. Yes, you could experiment with something like Redis, though I'm not convinced that it would necessarily be much better. Another option would be to take whatever it is you build using the data, and cache *that* -- maybe an HTML page.